# pytorch: inception v3 parameter empty error

Tags: pytorch

I am using inception_v3 from torchvision.models as my base model and adding an FC layer at the end to get features. However, I am getting an empty parameter error.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.models as models

class Baseline(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, out_size):
        super().__init__()
        model = models.inception_v3(pretrained=True)
        model.fc = nn.Linear(2048, out_size)
        model.aux_logits = False

        # Freeze model weights
        for param in model.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False



        self.parameters = nn.ParameterList()

    def forward(self, image):
        x = model(image)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = model.fc = (x)
        return x
```

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that you are updating `self.parameters` with an empty `nn.ParameterList`  which is not required here.

`self.parameters` will already have all the parameters your Baseline class has, including those of `inception_v3` and `nn.Linear`. When you are updating them at the end with an empty list, you are essentially deleting all of the previously stored parameters.